# How to redirect to another page after validation? And also want to pass the values to the next page

Tags: reactjs

**This is a function ValidateUser that validates and returns some data**

```
ValidateUser=(e)=>{
e.preventDefault();
axios.post('http://localhost/backend-mall-management/Login/Validate.php',this.state)
.then(res => {
if(res.data){
var Username=res.data.Username;
var User_Id=res.data.User_Id;
var Name=res.data.Name;
var Email=res.data.Email;
if(Username=='admin' || Username=='admin1' || Username=='admin2'){

      *From here I want the next page to render say AdminPage.*
}
else{

      *Also here I want the next page to render say ManagrePage.*
}
}else{
alert("Invaild Username or Password!!");
      this.setState({
            Username:'',
            Password:''
   });
```

**Render has the form.**

```
<input type="submit" name="sign-in" value="Sign In" onClick={this.ValidateUser}/>
```

**This calls the ValidateUser. All the components are rendered through App.js. It has this for routing.**

```
<BrowserRouter >
    <div className='App'>
      <Switch>
      <Route exact path='/' component={HomePage}/>
      <Route exact path='/AdminPage' component={AdminPage}/>
      </Switch>

    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use *history* to programmatically navigate inside your app:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

let history = useHistory();

...
if(Username=='admin' || Username=='admin1' || Username=='admin2'){
   history.push('/AdminPage');
} else {
   history.push('/'); // redirect to home page
}
```

Comment: Thank You Vlad. But still this hook isn't working. It is redirecting back to home page.

Comment: It's weird (: It should work. Please have a look at this article
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Hooks/usehistory